# Awestruct in Docker Container via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker, rubygems, awestruct

I want to use **awestruct** inside a docker container to build my website.
Everything seems to work but at the end I receive a message in Jenkins job:
[Jenkins Job Error](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/85907ec257982e6fce223d98d6d44ec4)
When I run the docker container directly on the server (not via Jenkins job) with:
`docker run -i -t --rm --volume  /home/jenkins/workspace/myWebsite :/home/jenkins/myWebsite:Z  --name myWebsite_Container mbiarnes/myWebsite:latest /bin/bash`
 I can access directly the container.
I can do a `rake setup` ([rake setup output](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/391a95e8d5fcf848dd81f08da183eaa8)). But when doing a `rake clean build` I get an [error](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/540538bba0838122a7447c5565a239cb)
I tried nearly everything but I cannot advance.
This is my [Dockerfile](https://github.com/mbiarnes/dockerTests/blob/master/Dockerfile).
When doing `awestruct --version` I get *`bash: awestruct: command not found`*
like **awestruct** is not installed, but in [rake setup output](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/391a95e8d5fcf848dd81f08da183eaa8#file-gistfile1-txt-L49) you can see that **awestruct 0.5.7** is used. Also during the building of docker image I didn't receive any errors and I can see in the [logs](https://gist.github.com/mbiarnes/f2a26844873ea9bf05e2f56c342d7bab#file-gistfile1-txt-L64) that **awestruct** is installed succesfully.